# Choosing where to put validations?

Tags: validation, hanami

Consider this snippet from [the "Getting Started" guide](http://hanamirb.org/guides/getting-started/):

```
module Web::Controllers::Books
  class Create
    include Web::Action

    expose :book

    params do
      param :book do
        param :title,  presence: true
        param :author, presence: true
      end
    end

    def call(params)
      if params.valid?
        @book = BookRepository.create(Book.new(params[:book]))

        redirect_to '/books'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Notice the validations on `title` and `author`, which live here in the controller action.  My question is: Why are these validations on the action params rather than on the `Book` entity?  That is, assuming the validations *were* on `Book`, you could write something like:

```
def call(params)
  book = Book.new(params)
  if book.valid?
    @book = BookRepository.create(Book.new(params[:book]))

    redirect_to '/books'
  end
end
```

and just get rid of the `params` block altogether.  This seems more natural to me, and would promote easier re-use of the validations across different actions.

Are there advantages to the `params` method that I'm not seeing?  Are there drawbacks to placing the validations on the `Book` entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Validations & Coercion](http://hanamirb.org/guides/actions/parameters/) section in the official guide explains why you should have validations on your requests, and not on your models.

To summarize it, here are the two major reasons:

1. From an architectural point of view, invalid inputs should never be allowed to enter your system so it is better to completely skip them at the controller level rather than creating a model just for validation as this is a pretty expensive operation.
2. It is possible to have multiple requests that work on the same model. If you have validations at the model level, you will also need to take into account the different scenarios for these requests which again is the controller's responsibility, not the model's.

Still, if you can do with the above scenarios in your business logic, it would come down to the matter of personal preference.

Comment: Since posting this, I've read up on the subject more, and your point in 2. is really the key reason to keep validations out of entities.  However, it still seem wrong to me to put them in actions, as that couples them to the delivery mechanism.  I'd appreciate your feedback [on this followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136512/implementing-form-objects-in-hanami), where I elaborate on that point.